# Stopping setInterval inside ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, setinterval

I just want to test multiple MQTT clients sending messages at different intervals inside a Node v8.9.1 app. **At the moment this code fails even for just one client**. I cannot understand why `clearInterval` is not working inside this class:

```js
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

export default class MQTTClient {
constructor(url, conf, period) {
    this.url = url;
    this.conf = conf;
    this.period = period;
    this.messages = 0;
    this.client = null;
    this.interval = null;
}

getTotalMessages() {
    return this.messages;
}

connect() {
    this.client = mqtt.connect(this.url, this.conf);

    this.client.on('connect', () => {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.client.publish(`u${this.conf.clientId}`, 'Hello mqtt');
            this.messages += 1;
            if (this.messages === 3) {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                console.log(this.interval);
                this.client.end();
            }
        }, this.period);
    });

    this.client.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(`${this.conf.clientId} error`, error);
    });
}
}
```

The `console.log` statement actually prints something like:

```
Timeout {
    '0': null,
    _called: false,
    _idleTimeout: -1,
    _idlePrev: null,
    _idleNext: null,
    _idleStart: 5580,
    _onTimeout: null,
    _timerArgs: undefined,
    _repeat: null,
    _destroyed: false,
    [Symbol(asyncId)]: 134,
    [Symbol(triggerAsyncId)]: 123 }
```

To be more complete, I call this class inside a unit test made with Jest:

```js
test('Multiple MQTT messages', (done) => {
    const mqttURL = `mqtt://localhost:${config.moscaSettings.port}`;
    expect(config.moscaSettings.port).toBe(1883);
    const conf = {
        clientId: concurrencyTokens[0].value,
        username: concurrencyTokens[0].owner,
        password: concurrencyTokens[0].value,
    };

    const mqttClient = new MQTTClient(mqttURL, conf, 1000);
    mqttClient.connect();

    // terminates the test after five seconds
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const res = await Messages.remove({ userName: user }).exec();
        expect(mqttClient.getTotalMessages()).toBe(3);
        expect(res.result.n).toBe(3);
        done();
    }, 5000);
}, 10000);
```

So I cannot understand why it doesn't work. Using arrow functions guarantees me that `this` is referring to the class, but interval does not stop.
Any ideas?

Comment: How many clients? If it's more than one, the second and so on will overwrite the previous interval, thus making it unstoppable because you've lost the reference to it.

Comment: `connect()` must be executed multiple times, creating multiple intervals. A good way to confirm this would be to change the global variable `interval` to an array and push the interval to this array and then inspect it later. It probably has multiple intervals, which you could loop through and clear them all

Comment: @KevinB: at the moment it can't work with just one, but interval variable can be moved inside the class, so that's not a problem.

Comment: @CharlieMartin: connect should be called just once per client. At the moment I'm just calling it once for just one client.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo but shouldn't you assign the setInterval call result to `this.interval` instead of `interval` ? -- Well considering the edit history, I think it's a typo :) you should reedit your post

Comment: @Logar: you're right, it's a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CharlieMartin pointed out in a comment, I found that `connect` is called multiple times (but that's another problem), so filling an array with all intervals references solved the problem. I was able to detect it also by logging `setInterval` object and seeing that it had a different `[Symbol(asyncId)]` in some printing.
Thanks for support.

```js
    this.client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('on connect');
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.client.publish(`u${this.conf.clientId}`, 'Hello mqtt');
            this.messages += 1;
            if (this.messages === 3) {
                this.clearIntervals();
                this.client.end();
            }
        }, this.period);
        this.intervals.push(interval);
    });
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified version of what you're doing is working fine. Verify each reference to **this.property** is correct. Also verify you are not landing in OnError.

```js
var c = (function(){
    let interval;
    let count = 0;
    let express = () => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
         count++;
            if (count === 3) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            console.log(interval);
        }, 100);
    };
    return {onThing:express};
})();
c.onThing();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure I'm not landing in `onError`, there's a `console.error` in that function and I can also see that more than 3 messages are published. I know that this can be written in other ways, I'd like to know what's wrong with this implementation